# Getting gzip to work in wordpress with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, gzip

I'm using the following snippet (taken from [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)) to gzip files.  I don't have too much experience with this kindof thing, but it seems as though it isn't working.

Google PageSpeed is listing out a whole bunch of files which *should* be compressed but aren't (all of my js and css I think)

Looking at firefox's `net` panel, I think I've verified that these are **not** being compressed, though I do see `Accept Encoding: gzip, deflate`

Part of the problem is maybe the `Content-Type` of the js is set to `application/x-javascript` which doesn't appear to be referenced in the below code. The css *is* however `text/css`

Honestly (haven't done much googling on this yet), I don't even know how to change the content-type of things, so if thats part of the problem, and its an easy eplanation (or snippet), than please include it in your answer.

If it matters, I'm using WordPress....

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
  <IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
  </IfModule>


  <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
    # Legacy versions of Apache
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is other similar solved question with several options (despite the reference to the hosting, question and answer is enough generic) here: [How to make gzip work on 1and1 shared host WordPress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420992/how-to-make-gzip-work-on-1and1-shared-host-wordpress-site)

Review that your Apache has the required modules installed and loaded (mod_setenvif, filter_module, mod_headers, mod_deflate, mod_gzip).