# How to make gzip work on 1and1 shared host WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, gzip

YSlow is telling me that my css should be compressed, but after several hours of tinkering, I cannot for the life of me get gzip to work for my website.  At this point, I'm not even sure if the performance increase (will there be one?) will be worth the effort.

I'm running a WordPress site on a 1&1 shared hosting account.

Honestly, I don't really know what I'm doing with this stuff, and can't seem to get an appropriate setup.  I read in a few places that with 1&1, "modules Apache mod_deflate and mod_gzip are not installed.", so I assume this is part of the problem.

**I have tried the following code:**

This one doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>  
    mod_gzip_on         Yes  
    mod_gzip_dechunk    Yes  
    mod_gzip_item_include file          \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$  
    mod_gzip_item_include handler       ^cgi-script$  
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text\.*  
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*  
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image\.*  
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*  
</IfModule>
```

This causes a 500 error

```
<Location />
# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</Location>
```

This (from html5 boilerplate) doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
  <IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/x-icon
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
  </IfModule>


  <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
    # Legacy versions of Apache
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

This one Doesnt seem to do anything...

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript
```

I followed the tutorial found here

```
(http://mrrena.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-compress-php-and-other-text.html)
```

but this essentially completely broke the appearance of my site.

---

Tried this in my Functions.php, and it seemed to compress my html, but leaves some js and css uncompressed

```
if(extension_loaded("zlib") && (ini_get("output_handler") != "ob_gzhandler"))
    add_action('wp', create_function('', '@ob_end_clean();@ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 1);'));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, after a while I figured out how to compress html, css and js files having a 1&1 Webhosting package. Deflate is not supported!

For the dynamic content you add php.ini to your root directory of your website. Content of php.ini:

```
zlib.output_compression =1
zlib.output_compression_level =9
```

Of course you can also choose another compression level, 9 is the highest (and causing the highest server load). That will compress your the dynamically generated html file.

To compress static files (css, js and images...) you need to modify the .htaccess file. For that append

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

to your .htaccess file (you find that file in the root directory of your website - else create it).
But the compression is not done automatically. So you have to compress the files on your own! Use e.g. 7-zip and compress the js and css files with .gz -> the result should be e.g. stylesheet.css.gz.
Then upload the file to the same directory as the file you just compressed.

Now it should work!

PS: compression is not always useful especially when the file is very small. So check the differences before and after compression.

Comment: Works great. Could you add a way to only do this for specific file types, for example css and js?

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like you have exhausted your option. Looking at the above it seems like the host indeed doesn't have mod_deflate or mod_gzip. So I guess you are just out of luck.

The PHP solution is indeed only for the HTML. So just stick with that one. HTML is also the best place to add compression, as, most of the time, the CSS and JS are only downloaded on the first page.

You could redirect the request to CSS and JS though a PHP script, and use the PHP to compress. But I would not go there, as you would also have to implement `304 Not modified` and set the appropriate expires headers.

Comment: It feels much better giving up when someone else tells you you should ;-) Thanks!  I'll just use that final snippet listed in my question.

Answer (score 6):

Enable gzip compression 
The gzip compression can be activated in php.ini with the following code:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_compression_level = 9
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: it's been quite a while since I tackled this problem, but if memory serves, a 1&1 Shared hosting account does NOT allow for configuration with `php.ini`

Comment: Second this, worked for me on 1&1. Is there any chance anyone can explain what the `code here` does?

Comment: this just worked perfectly for me, for WordPress on 1&1

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old now, but I've found a solution that works for me.

Add a file called "php.ini" to the root folder containing the following;

```
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_compression_level = 9
```

Then (and this is the bit you might not expect) add the following to your .htaccess file;

```
AddType x-mapp-php6 .html .htm .php
```

Yes, that's right. I've put `php6` in that. Apparently that will run the latest stable version of PHP (currently 5.4) which will allow gzip compression. This will also run `.html` and `.htm` files through the PHP parser, which means that they can be compressed (files not run through the PHP parser will not be compressed). Feel free to add any other extensions that you want to be run through PHP (`.xml` for example).

By the way, if you do run `.xml` files through PHP, remember to set the header declaring it as an xml file, otherwise it won't work properly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me,

First you have to copy the php.ini in all directory.
(1and1 provided a script to facilitate this manipulation in their faq)
with this content :

```
zlib.output_compression =1
zlib.output_compression_level =9
```

Then add this in the htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_item_exclude file \.(gz|zip|xsl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/html$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/plain$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^image/x-icon$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^httpd/unix-directory$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/javascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/x-js$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/ecmascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/ecmascript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/vbscript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/fluffscript$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/css$
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable compression by adding this code into your .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-fastphp application/x-httpd-eruby 

</IfModule>
```