# How to enable gzip on a website hosted on 1and1 server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've already read the topic [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420992/how-to-make-gzip-work-on-1and1-shared-host-wordpress-site). But I cannot comment it.
So, I did the changes in the file php.ini

```
zlib.output_compression =1
zlib.output_compression_level =9
```

(in my case I used compression_level =5).

Testing the gzip here >> [GIDZipTest](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) and here >> [HTTP Compression Test](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test) I see that it is working.

However, in the guide there is another step.
The second step is to edit the file .htaccess.
But here my question:

I have this .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

the topic suggest to put in the file .htaccess this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

as you can see, it is similar. How can I add everything in the file?

1) Should I implement the different lines in one file like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

2) Or should I do two different sections like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

or what?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can best add those separately. Basically WordPress can change anything between the START & END WordPress comments. So, you should never add anything in between (unless WP tells you to, obviously).

So, for gzip - assuming this code is correct, I didn't verify - you could do it like this:

```
# BEGIN gzip
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
# END gzip

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

However, when your gzip is working already, you do not need to add it. Perhaps you use a plugin that takes care of this, like W3 Total Cache?

---

update:

I'm not familiar with zlib. According to the source you referred to, this is for dynamic content, like php and what's added to .htaccess is for static content, like stylesheets and Javascript. So, unless you have a plugin that takes care of compression, perhaps not everything is compressed on your site. It might be good to verify this. Also, if you use cache all content may be static (HTML), in which case the .htaccess might be more relevant. I'd suggest to try it.

For the record, before switching to W3TC I used this in .htaccess for gzip compression:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

I've no clue whether or not it would work for 1and1 though.

---

update 2:
1&1 [recommends](http://community.1and1.com/increase-client-performance-with-mod-deflate/) the following for gzip on their 'performance' servers:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It is already working, without the code... but what does the second code do?

I'm not sure if add w3 total cache, I'm reading review of ppl that had huge issue with the website after installing those kind of plugin...

Comment: I'm using W3TC with XCache (http://xcache.lighttpd.net/) and it's quite an improvement compared to Wordfence Falcon or WP Super Cache (which are easier to set up), but it was a bit of a struggle indeed. It's a matter of finding the right settings for your site. - I'll update my answer.

Comment: So, I'm not skilled with coding, and I don't want to do a mess... should I try adding this code?

    `# BEGIN gzip
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions Inherit
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} (gzip.*) 
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.+\.gz$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.gz [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
# END gzip`

Comment: Yes, if it breaks something, you can simply remove it again, but I would expect it will do nothing, or it will compress files that currently do not get compressed. Perhaps use http://gzipwtf.com/ first to see if your CSS is currently compressed.

Comment: Tried with [gzipwtf.com](http://gzipwtf.com) but nothig... with or without that code it doesn't compress css and tons of things... if you want to try, the website is clicksforcakes.com

Comment: I don't know 1and1, so I don't know what makes it hard... Have you tried the .htaccess code I used before W3TC? Else you could try a plugin for it. E.g. [WP Performance Score Booster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-performance-score-booster/) only has a few settings. You can turn on gzip and leverage browser caching.

Comment: yes, I tried the both codes. nothing with each one. I'll give to the WP Performance Score Booster a try..

Comment: nothing with wp performance score booster. actually it made it worst. at the moment I'm getting 24 resources (on 30) that are not compressed at all..

Comment: I updated the answer with info from 1&1. If that doesn't help, best contact their support. https://twitter.com/1and1help/

Comment: Should I have to add the code in update2 and also the update1?

Comment: I think you tried the first update already. The 2nd is from 1&1, so I'd try that. This is for their 'performance' servers though. In the comments on the page you can read it doesn't work for shared hosting, yet it is said that adding '<?php ob_start(“ob_gzhandler”); ?>' to the "top of your PHP application" should do the trick... That would be header.php, but you would need a child theme for this, else the change will go lost when you update the theme. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes ... Which is why I would contact support instead. It really shouldn't be a big deal to turn on gzip.

Comment: your comment are really helpful. I've already contacted the 1&1 support, but they are not helpful at all. I have the child theme but I think I'll not mess up with the code... I'm planning to change host in a couple of months...